# Passing popup link so it shows on the address bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm very familiar with php/js/ajax, but I'm a little confused as to how to pass the popup link to the address bar.

Basically I have a custom jquery popup. Let's say I click on a link that loads the popup, I want to pass parameters to the address bar so that it reads out the address of whatever I want.

So let's say my page that contains the videos with the links is:
mydomain.com/videos/index.php

and when a video is clicked I want it to read the following in the address bar:
mydomain.com/video/youtubeid

I actually have it all set up to work on the video page if they were to come back to that link. I don't want a popup to come up obviously. The popup links page is like /video/video_pop.php

How would I go about doing this? Is there some way to change the address bar? Is this a htaccess rewrite thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript history API to change the address in the address bar without reloading the page. Mozilla provides instructions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Actually I did, I found this. Thanks buddy. Pretty stupid how I lost reputation now I can't even upvote you.